# statement.executeQuery () does not working

Tags: java, jdbc, android-asynctask

```
statement = conRecieved.createStatement();
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("Select * from actor");
```

In this if I check if it returns any result, but it does not enter this if

```
if (resultSet.next()) {
   Toast.makeText (getActivity (), "ResultsetWorks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show ();
} else {
   Toast.makeText (getActivity (), "REsult set no results", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show ();
}
```

The process of connecting to the database is performed in an AsynTask class that gives me the connection, the created Connection object, Where is the fault? I tried casting the received connection but it does not work.

```
AsyncTaskConexion asyncTaskConexion = new AsyncTaskConexion(getActivity(), new GetConnection() {
    @Override
    public void getConnection(Connection conexion) {
        if(conexion!=null){
            Connection conRecieved = (Connection )conexion;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I fixed it by running the query in a separate thread, not using the mainthread. I do not know if this is the best solution but it works.

```
AsyncTaskConexion asyncTaskConexion = new AsyncTaskConexion(getActivity(), new GetConnection() {
        @Override
        public void getConnection(Connection conexion) {
            if(conexion!=null){
                Connection conexionRecibida = conexion;
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {                             
                            Statement statement = conexionRecibida.createStatement();
                            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("Select * from actor");
```

> with the method runOnUiThread(... you can iteract with the Ui elements

```
                            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                        if(resultSet.next()){
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"ResultsetWorks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }else{
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Empty ResultSet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Why are you giving me a negative votes? with no explains!? I will report this actions. This place is for teach people who its starting, like me.